# Redirect TCP MySQL connection to proxy

Tags: mysql, delphi, proxy, zeos

I have a Delphi application which connects to a MySQL published database on Internet with address like mysql01.example.com:3306.

However, my client computer is behind a proxy and I just can connect if I pass by the proxy. I use the ZeosLib to connect and it doesn't have proxy authentication.

Is it possible to forward connection to the proxy using some kind of proxy forward program? Is there another possibility to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

[Synapse framework](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) has a [socks proxy](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/blcksock.TSocksBlockSocket.html) implementation.

Or you can make it yourself (quite easy, since socks protocol is really simple, even version 5). See:

- [SOCKS 4 SPECS](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/socks/socks4/SOCKS4.protocol)
- [SOCKS 5 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928)
- [SOCKS 5 user/pass auth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1929)
- [SOCKS 5 GSS-API auth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1961)
- [Synapse blcksock code](http://gitorious.org/delphi/synapse/blobs/a613150d042f105ed9f2e1bf2204010cc54dc780/blcksock.pas)

Comment: I didn't urdeerstand how to use the Synapse to do this. Is it possible to post an example?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand how to implement this. I'm waiting for another solution

Comment: I've created a class derivated of TSocksBlockSocket but didn't urdestand how to link this with the ZeosLib ZConnection